# Elementor Custom Widget (add_control) - How to get to this data inside my array ? (Background URL)

Tags: arrays, wordpress, background, widget, elementor

I have created a custom Elementor widget, which have a specific control for selecting an SVG icon for my slider.

Here is my code :

```
$this->add_control(
            'arrows_icon_left',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Arrow left' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::ICONS,
                'default' => [
                    'value' => 'fas fa-chevron-left',
                    'library' => 'solid',
                ],
                'selectors' => [
                    '{{WRAPPER}} .swiper-button-prev' => 'background-image: url({{VALUE}});',
                ],
            ]
        );
```

Everything is OK.
The control and the widget work fine !

Except that I don't know how to access to the background URL path. :(

On my website, the css property display : background-image( Array() )

[see the browser inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyfiq.png)

So, I have put this test

```
var_dump($settings[])
```

And I get this now :

```
["arrows_icon_left"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["value"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(66) "//website.local/files/2021/04/check-mark.svg"
      ["id"]=>
      int(1128)
    }
    ["library"]=>
    string(3) "svg"
  }
```

When I test :

```
var_dump($settings[arrows_icon_left][value][url])
```

I access to the URL no problem.

So I've tried many ways to access to it like VALUE :

VALUE.url

VALUE.value.url

{{VALUE}}{{URL}}

{{VALUE}}{{VALUE}}{{URL}}

But nothing works. :(((

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The Icon Control provides two possibilities of accessing Icons, first is an icon font from the fa library which is integrated by ::before, for this you need to add the value (which is a class) to the wrapper element.

Second, there is the custom Icon, which is integrated as an SVG Image.

I don't know if you have the need to distinguish between those two as in your question you are asking for the Custom Icon.
As far as I know there is no placeholder for that in the selectors key of the control's array.

I have solved this by accessing the value in the render method as follows:

```
if ( !is_array( $settings['icon']['value'] ) and !empty( $settings['icon']['value'] ) ) {
    echo '<div class="wrapper ' . $settings['icon']['value'] . '"></div>';
} elseif ( is_array( $settings['icon']['value'] ) and !empty( $settings['icon']['value']['url'] ) ) {
    echo '<div class="wrapper"><img src="' . $settings['icon']['value']['url'] . '" /></div>';
}
```